# Invoking $mdDialog message dialog from node module

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-material

In order to show up a  $mdDialog  message dialog instead of a native alert message box, could you please give me some hints for the way how to require an AngularJS Material component to show up a $mdDialog in Node.js style module which will be bundled into a client side.

NB:
I'm using browserify in order to bundle all required module at a app.js file which will be injected later into an Angular JS as a constant.

I already injected all AngularJS and AngularJS Material into the client side via bower.

```
'use strict';

var CustomModeler = require('./custom-modeler/CustomModeler');

angular.module('ng-app')
   .constant('CustomModeler', CustomModeler)
  .constant('contextMenu', $.contextMenu)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a GitHub repo where people can get more information about what you are trying to do? Are you just trying to create a library to publish to NPM?

Comment: I'm trying to inject $mdDialog object which was insatanciated in angular js controller  into npm module.

Comment: There are a number of examples in the demos section of the docs: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog. Most of the details are in the Service docs for $mdDialog: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog. There's some additional minimal information in the component docs: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDialog.